# Ingress resource having backend kubernetes services in multiple namespace

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two applications deployed in different namespace in Google Kontainer engine(GKE). I want to use a single ingress resource (Google Load Balancer) to point to both the application using path based routing. Is it possible to have backend kubernetes services in multiple namespace behind a single ingress resource. If possible, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to setup an nginx ingress controller and deploy ingress resources per each namespace: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17088#issuecomment-221393102